# Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailPageRenderer

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I created a Xamarin.Forms app which has a deep link for reset password. When I click reset link from the mail, it opens my app. It works fine on ios version but it crashes when I tried to open a link on Android version. App crashed only if the app was in the background, if it is not in the background then it works. The error message when app crash is as follow.

> Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailPageRenderer from native handle 0x10001d (key_handle 0x9802156).

I googled this and some of the StackOverflow thread says that I need to add Constructors with (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) parameter which is **obsolete** in **Xamarin.Forms 2.5** version and I can not do that because I am using Xamarin.Forms 3.5+ version.

Comment: Show code of `MasterDetailPageRenderer` in project.When android in background ,some logic need to be dealed with.

Comment: I did not create any Renderer for MasterDetailPageRenderer